# How to cite the number of articles with a specific keyword?

Tags: publications, citations, scopus, keywords

In the introduction of a paper I'm writing, I want to make the observation that the specific field we're studying is experiencing a huge boom. I don't know if I need to back this affirmation by citing the articles database I'm using (Scopus) or how should I do it.

[image: Keyword usage over time]

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile noting the recent focus the field has brought to the area of research. This is touching on the field of meta-analysis, or specifically, bibliometrics. You could use a version of this figure and describe your search terms (perhaps in supplementary materials) and the database (Scopus) you used to illustrate the point. It is worth noting that what you can say about this trend without further analysis is limited so making broad claims should be avoided.